# Error while adding Date to Database

Tags: spring-mvc

While adding Date from jsp to database through Hibernate i got the error.
please let me know if anyone knows the solution for this.
appreciate for your help. below is my code snippet.

**register.jsp**

```
<form:input path="date" id="datepicker"/>
```

**Registration.java**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class Registration {
private Timestamp date;
    public Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/library/*")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value="success", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("register") Registration register, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(register.getFirstName());
        registerService.addUsers(register);
        return "register";
    }
}
```

while adding date from jsp to database i got the below error

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'register' on field 'date': rejected value [25/11/2014]; codes [typeMismatch.register.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.sql.Timestamp,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [register.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.sql.Timestamp] for property 'date': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:818)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:659)
```

Comment: Your date variable in Registration class is of type TimeStamp for which valid data looks like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]` where as your input `is dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `java.util.Date` object instead of `TimeStamp` object. Following code will solve your problem,

**At your model class, Registration.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Registration {
private Date date;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**At your controller class, HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/library/*")
public class HelloController {

@Override
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   dateFormat.setLenient(false);
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}

@RequestMapping(value="success", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("register") Registration register, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(register.getFirstName());
    registerService.addUsers(register);
    return "register";
}
}
```

After submitting your jsp form, all the parameters in the request by default will be of type `String`. In `Spring-MVC`, it's the duty `initBinder` to convert all those String values into respective type and bind it with Model class variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be mapping between timestamp object and date string that is received from JSP.

You can solve this problem any of below ways.

1. Either change your Register class date variable type to String type and later on in your     service or DAO layer you can convert it to the TimeStamp Object like below.

   Date date = new Date(date_received_as_string);

   Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
2. Or you can write your JSON Serializer.First annotate the date variable with JSONSerialize.

   @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)

   private Timestamp date;

After you provide implementation of CustomSerializer class,like below.

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        //Now write you code for converting string to TimeStamp Object.

    }
}
```

In the same you can also write JsonDeserializer for TimeStamp Object.